# How do I check if pandas df column value exists based on value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below

| Year | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 1 | 100 |
| 2017 | 1 | 102 |
| 2017 | 1 | 105 |
| 2018 | 1 | 98 |
| 2016 | 2 | 121 |
| 2016 | 2 | 101 |
| 2016 | 2 | 133 |
| 2018 | 3 | 102 |

I want to check if the ID only exists for the year 2018 only. My desired output is as below:

| Year | ID | Value | ID_only_in_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2017 | 1 | 102 | 0 |
| 2017 | 1 | 105 | 0 |
| 2018 | 1 | 98 | 0 |
| 2016 | 2 | 121 | 0 |
| 2016 | 2 | 101 | 0 |
| 2016 | 2 | 133 | 0 |
| 2018 | 3 | 102 | 1 |

Please, how can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare Year for `2018` and then test if all values are only `2018`:

```
mask = df['Year'].eq(2018).groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')
```

Another idea is test if Year is not `2018`, filter `ID` for not matched at least one non `2018` row and last invert mask by `~` for get only `2018` groups:

```
mask = ~df['ID'].isin(df.loc[df['Year'].ne(2018), 'ID'])
```

Last convert mask to integers:

```
df['ID_only_in_2018'] = mask.astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['ID_only_in_2018'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['ID_only_in_2018'] = mask.view('i1')
```

---

```
print (df)
   Year  ID  Value  ID_only_in_2018
0  2016   1    100                0
1  2017   1    102                0
2  2017   1    105                0
3  2018   1     98                0
4  2016   2    121                0
5  2016   2    101                0
6  2016   2    133                0
7  2018   3    102                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test in your group `ID`if year is unique and if this unique year is 2018:

```
df['ID_only_in_2018'] = df.groupby('ID')['Year'] \
                          .apply(lambda y: (y.nunique() == 1) &
                                (y == 2018)).astype(int)
```

```
>>> df
   Year  ID  Value  ID_only_in_2018
0  2016   1    100                0
1  2017   1    102                0
2  2017   1    105                0
3  2018   1     98                0
4  2016   2    121                0
5  2016   2    101                0
6  2016   2    133                0
7  2018   3    102                1
```

Answer (score 0):

For each group of `ID`s, we can check if their unique `Year`s are equal to `[2018]` with `isin`. Then we can `map` all `ID`s in the frame with that:

```
only_2018 = df.groupby("ID").Year.unique().isin([[2018]])
df["ID_only_in_2018"] = df.ID.map(only_2018).astype(int)
```

where the double brackets around 2018 is because `unique` gives back a list so we put the other one and `astype` is to convert True/False to 1/0.

to get

```
>>> df

   Year  ID  Value  ID_only_in_2018
0  2016   1    100                0
1  2017   1    102                0
2  2017   1    105                0
3  2018   1     98                0
4  2016   2    121                0
5  2016   2    101                0
6  2016   2    133                0
7  2018   3    102                1
```

---

`only_2018` is:

```
ID
1    False
2    False
3     True
```

Comment: hmmm, interesting. But seems buggy, if compare by list with multiple values like `df.groupby("ID").Year.unique().isin([[2016, 2017, 2018]])`. For one element list working well.

Comment: @Emmy seems to need for one single year but `map(tuple)` and checking against a tuple make it work for multiple values; something interesting going on with `isin` when lists are involved, perhaps I should look into the source code... thanks for the feedback for multiple values.

Comment: Ya, it seems rare used so it should be buggy. Btw, compare sets here should be possible way for avoid use `isin` with list.

Answer (score 0):

1st recreate the exampe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"Year" : 2016, "ID" : 1, "Value" : 100},
       {"Year" : 2017, "ID" : 1, "Value" : 102},
       {"Year" : 2017, "ID" : 1, "Value" : 105},
       {"Year" : 2018, "ID" : 1, "Value" : 98},
       {"Year" : 2016, "ID" : 2, "Value" : 121},
       {"Year" : 2016, "ID" : 2, "Value" : 101},
       {"Year" : 2016, "ID" : 2, "Value" : 133},
       {"Year" : 2018, "ID" : 3, "Value" : 102}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And take a close look at the aggregated data to see what's what.

```
df.groupby("ID")['Year'].apply(list)
```

Which returns the following:

```
ID 1    [2016, 2017, 2017, 2018] 
   2          [2016, 2016, 2016] 
   3                      [2018] Name: Year, dtype: object
```

So ID 1 appears in all 4 years, ID 2 appears 3 times but only ever with 2016, and ID 3 appears only once, for a single year, 2018.

Changing the aggregation function from `list` to `set` returns a slightly different view:

```
df.groupby("ID")['Year'].apply(set)

ID
1    {2016, 2017, 2018}
2                {2016}
3                {2018}
Name: Year, dtype: object
```

Which shows how ID 1 is spread across 3 years, and IDs 2 and 3 are spread against only a single year each.

If you want to test that a given ID then is associated with only one year, you could save and refer to one of these dictionaries, testing the values returned for a chosen year.

```
unique_lookup_set = dict(df.groupby("ID")['Year'].apply(set))

def contains_and_only_contains(value, collection):
    if value in collection and len(set(collection))==1:
         return 1
    else:
         return 0
```

Now try generating a series with the answers, to test it out:

```
df.apply(lambda x : contains_and_only_contains(2018, unique_lookup_set.get(x['ID'])), axis=1)

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7     1
dtype: int
```

Good, and finally, include that series into the original dataframe to get the final output.

```
df['ID_only_in_2018']=df.apply(lambda x : contains_and_only_contains(2018, unique_lookup_set.get(x['ID'])), axis=1)

df
```

|  | Year | ID | Value | ID_only_in_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016 | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 2017 | 1 | 102 | 0 |
| 2 | 2017 | 1 | 105 | 0 |
| 3 | 2018 | 1 | 98 | 0 |
| 4 | 2016 | 2 | 121 | 0 |
| 5 | 2016 | 2 | 101 | 0 |
| 6 | 2016 | 2 | 133 | 0 |
| 7 | 2018 | 3 | 102 | 1 |